# Fit Set Definition into two lines

Tags: equations

What is the best way to fit the definition into two lines, so they don't ruin the layout?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,reqno,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}     % ams stuff should be before font loading
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % should be after font loading
\usepackage{fixltx2e,babel}


\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}    % bibtex package
%\usepackage{typearea}           % custom type area
%   \areaset[0mm]{135mm}{210mm}  % typearea configuration
%   \topmargin5mm                % typearea configuration
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\overline{R_1}=\left\{(j_1,j_2) \colon \exists r\in R\,\exists a=(v,w)\in A^r\Big(w\ne D^r \wedge (j_1,j_2)\in J_v^r\times J_w^r \wedge j_2<j_1+\Gamma_a^r+c_w^r\Big)\right\}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\overline{R_2}=\left\{(j_1,j_2) \colon \exists a=(v,w)\in A^r\,\exists (r_1,r_2)\in L_a\Big((j_1,j_2)\in J_v^{r_1}\times J_v^{r_2} \wedge j_2<j_1+s_a^{r_1r_2} + \text{min}(\Gamma_a^{r_1}- \Gamma_a^{r_2} ,0)\Big)\right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\overline{R_3}=\left\{(j_1,j_2) \colon \exists v\in V\,\exists (r_1,r_2) \in U_v \Big(a = (u,v) \in A^r \wedge (j_1,j_2)\in J_v^{r_1}\times J_v^{r_2} \wedge j_2 + \Gamma_a^{r_2} < j_1+ \Gamma_a^{r_1} +s_a^{r_1r_2}\Big)\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there may be better ways to break these lines, but this may suffice.

i've changed `\left` and `\right` to explicit `\big` braces to avoid
"matching" problems, and i've grouped the three equations into an
`align` environment to get better control over spacing between them.

i'm not entirely happy with leaving `\in` at the ends of the first lines,
but the second lines are quite long, and i didn't want to have to break
the second equation to a third line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,reqno,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}     % ams stuff should be before font loading
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % should be after font loading
\usepackage{fixltx2e,babel}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{align}
\overline{R_1}&=
 \begin{aligned}[t]
  \Big\{
  &(j_1,j_2) \colon \exists r\in R\,\exists a=(v,w)\in\\
 & A^r\Big(w\ne D^r \wedge (j_1,j_2)\in J_v^r\times J_w^r \wedge j_2<j_1+\Gamma_a^r+c_w^r\Big)%\right\}
  \Big\}
 \end{aligned}
\\
\overline{R_2}&=
 \begin{aligned}[t]
  \Big\{ &(j_1,j_2) \colon \exists a=(v,w)\in A^r\,\exists (r_1,r_2)\in\\
  & L_a\Big((j_1,j_2)\in J_v^{r_1}\times J_v^{r_2} \wedge j_2<j_1+s_a^{r_1r_2} + \text{min}(\Gamma_a^{r_1}- \Gamma_a^{r_2} ,0)\Big)\Big\}
 \end{aligned}
\\
\overline{R_3}&=
 \begin{aligned}[t]
  \Big\{ (j_1,j_2) \colon & \exists v\in V\,\exists (r_1,r_2) \in\\
  & U_v \Big(a =
    \begin{aligned}[t] & (u,v) \in A^r \wedge (j_1,j_2)\in\\
     & J_v^{r_1}\times J_v^{r_2} \wedge j_2 + \Gamma_a^{r_2} < j_1+ \Gamma_a^{r_1} +s_a^{r_1r_2}\Big)\Big\}
 \end{aligned}
 \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]